# How to ffplay reversed audio?

Tags: ffmpeg, command-line, ffplay

How can I play the audio backwards with `ffplay`?

`ffplay -af reverse file.mp3` gives the error "Media type mismatch between the 'ffplay_abuffer' filter output pad 0 (audio) and the 'Parsed_reverse_0' filter input pad 0 (video)"

Comment: you also need the `areverse` filter to reverse the channels of the audio stream I think

Comment: @Gandhi `ffplay -af areverse ../file.wav` doesn't error, it opens the player, but also doesn't play for more than 0 seconds (seems frozen)

Comment: well another less elegant solution would be to reverse the audio, safe it as a new file and play that after that: `ffmpeg -i test.mp3 -af areverse test2.mp3` and `ffplay -i test2.mp3`, but I dont know if you want that...

Answer (score 1):

Pass a filtergraph to the [libavfilter input virtual device](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#lavfi):

```
ffplay -f lavfi amovie=file.mp3,areverse
```